# Driver not updating when rendering animation

Tags: rendering, animation, video-sequence-editor, drivers

Have you ever experienced such an issue? Driver not updating when rendering animation, but updating when single images are being rendered one by one?

---

Case description:
I created empty, linked to a motion tracker. Then I parented a plane to this empty and baked action of this plane.
Next I created driver for x offset of a Strip in Video Sequence Editor (Image of the setup below). 
Strip, which the driver is for, is moving nicely in the viewer and the Backdrop of the VSE, but when I try to render the animation (both to mp4 and PNG sequence) it doesn't.
What's more interesting, it is rendering fine when I try to render it frame by frame with F12.
Any Ideas? Is it a bug or I just forgot to turn something on?[image]

Comment: Have you tried animating it with F-Curves instead of drivers?

Comment: No I haven't. Usually I'm animating offset with F-Curves, but this time I need it to stick to the motion tracker. I'm not searching for alternative solution for the offset animation cause it's only dozen frames and I already rendered them. I just want to know if this driver behaviour is normal and I just didn't switch something or it's a bug and I should report it.

Comment: I don't have much experience with the motion tracking side of things but it does seem like a bug, so go ahead and report it. [Check this out.](https://www.blendernation.com/2013/09/29/reporting-bugs-in-blender/)

Comment: Same problem here... How did you resolve?

Comment: I didn't @BonecoSinforoso Just rendered everything frame by frame with F12.

Comment: @Mzidare Wow, I managed to solve my problem, but I forgot to come back here. In my case, I made a driver associated with an empty object, and I made all the modifications to that empty object. But it looks like you tried the same, but it didn't work. That's weird.